# owl-carousel not working on recently purchased template

Tags: javascript, html, css, owl-carousel

I recently purchased an HTML template called chalilac-charity and have two problems with the Owl Carousel not working as it should. I am not getting the help I need from the designers so I decided to try here. I will try to explain the issues as clearly as I can.

I have set up the template as it was purchased at [britishsupermarket.co.uk/chalilac-charity/](http://britishsupermarket.co.uk/chalilac-charity/)

Both problems are on the home page so other html pages do not show.

1. The first section after the navigation, with a title of "Latest Campaigns" operates fine on my laptop but is nowhere to be seen on mobile devices. The template is meant to be responsive, but this section does not work.
2. Under the section where clients details are shown with a purple background, just before the footer, I would like to auto scroll each box. Currently it does not.

I am not good at coding and would like some help with knowing what files I need to adjust/add.

Comment: Hey @travelguides, could you provide some of the code for us to work off of? Per problem 1, it would most likely be a CSS problem. For problem 2 what do you mean by auto scroll?

Answer (score 0):

1. When you look at the html, you can clearly see the hidden-xs class.
   Maybe you can edit it in the template or builder if it has one.

```html
<div class="about-area section-padding hidden-xs">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
```

2. To make it autoplay, go to main.js and find " testimonial-curosel" there. Change 'autoplay' from false to true

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. The designers have today updated their template after I said to them that it has now been broken for 4 years, so that is good. I have changed 'autoplay' to 'true' but it still does not work.